# Why is a part of my CSS style not applied?

Tags: html, css, django

Hii I'm kind of new so I might be making a rookie mistake but I have this HTML :

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block meta %}
<title>HOME</title>
{% endblock meta %}

{% block style %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'style.css' %}">
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Test</h1>
  </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

and this CSS

```
div.content {
    background-color: #DFBEBE;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

But it's not working... I tried with .content before but it also won't apply to my HTML. I applied a h1 css (with font) and it works just fine. It also works just fine with my previous projects(?) What did I do?

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors. The dev tools provide an **Inspector** / **Elements** and a **Network** tab. Please confirm: Is the resource _found_ (e.g. HTTP 200 response)? If not, which _actual URL_ is requested?

Comment: @user4642212 Hi! It is found. Turns out it's somehow my laptop problem :/ today when I tried running it again it works alright. Thankyou :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what your file structure is, but try something like this to link your stylesheet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
```

url_for() is what I have always used for my django projects, and it has worked every time. Note: you will need to have the stylesheet placed in the 'static' folder (unless you change 'static' in the function to something else).

Answer (score -1):

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">`
This is the easiest way to link them. Also check if the CSS and HTML are in the same folder

Answer (score -2):

You're probably not linking it correctly to the CSS in the HTML. Make sure your path is correct. If it is, `.content` should work fine.

[Here is the working JSFiddle with your code.](https://jsfiddle.net/qzy2hs48/)